# Issues with DataGrid binding and saving new rows to database

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, ado.net

I'm working on a simple windows application using SQL Server Compact with Entity Framework 6, I have a TreeView which is populated by a database, there is also a DataGrid which should be filled based on the selected node from TreeView. It looks like this [Image](http://i.imgur.com/7i94onK.jpg/)

Database Model:

- **Categories**

  - CategoryID
  - CategoryName
- **SubCategories**

  - SubID
  - SubName
  - CategoryID
- **Items**

  - ItemID
  - ItemName
  - SubID

---

I used this code to fill the DataGrid, everything was working just fine, but it won't save new rows to the database, editing existed rows is working though.

```
private void treeView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (treeView.SelectedNode.Level == 1)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = (from a in context.Items where a.SubID == (int)treeView.SelectedNode.Tag select a).ToList();
        dataGrid.DataSource = bs;
    }
}
```

---

So, I tried this. Saving new rows and editing existed ones worked, the thing is when selecting a node in TreeView it should only show the **Items** linked to the selected node, but it doesn't it adds the new query result to the old one, displaying both queries on the DataGrid, would be probably more if I selected more nodes.

```
private void treeView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (treeView.SelectedNode.Level == 1)
    {
        context.Items.Where(a => a.SubID == (int)treeView.SelectedNode.Tag).Load();
        dataGrid.DataSource = context.Items.Local.ToBindingList();
    }
}
```

---

There is one more thing I'm trying to do, when selecting a **Sub-Category** from TreeView I should get **Items** linked to this particular **Sub-Category** displayed on DataGrid, so is it possible when adding a new row in DataGrid it automatically set the **SubID** field in **Items** to the ID of selected node, linking this newly added **item** to the selected **Sub-Category** in TreeView.

Any help would be appreciated, and sorry if the solution is obvious, but all of this is new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the previously loaded items appearing when selecting another node, you should add this line in `treeView_AfterSelect`:

```
foreach(var item in context.Items.Local.ToList())
    context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
```

and then continue with

```
context.Items.Where(a => a.SubID == (int)treeView.SelectedNode.Tag).Load();
```

The added line removes the items from the change tracker and they will effectively be removed from the `Local` collection. The `Local` collection of a `DbSet<T>` contains all items that a context has ever loaded and have not been deleted. So with each `Load` statement you keep adding items to this collection. By changing their state to `Detached` the context no longer "knows" about their existence and they disappear from the `Local` collection.

Notice that you can't do

```
context.Items.Local.Clear();
```

because that will mark all items for delete, besides removing them from the `Local` collection. `SaveChanges` will delete the items from the database.

---

As for adding new items to a new subcategory, the best thing to do is add these items to an `Items` collection in `SubCategory`. Doing that, you don't need a foreign key value, which isn't know at that moment, but when calling `SaveChanges`, EF will save the SubCategory first and set the generated FK value in the Items "just in time".

It will look like

```
var subcat = new SubCategory();
var item = new Item();
subcat.Items.Add(item); // subcat.Items must have been initialized! 
context.SubCategories.Add(subcat); // Also marks item as Added
context.SaveChanges();
```

Now EF first saves `subcat`, reads its generated key value, sets `item`'s foreign key value and saves `item`, all in one transaction.

If you just create a new item for an existing `SubCategory` you can set `item.SubId` directly. But also `subcat.Items.Add(item)` can still be used, if `subcat` is attached to the context.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm getting this error on **Foreach** line when selecting another **SubCategory** from TreeView `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`  
I tried `context.Items.Local.Clear();` before and yes it didn't work.

Comment: Probably forgot a `ToList()`.

Comment: You're a lifesaver, thank you. It worked perfectly. It would be great if you can explain the code though, honestly I don't fully understand the problem or the solution, also the adding new items part, an example would be appreciated, if you don't mind. as I said I'm kinda new to this. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I explained a bit more.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, but thanks a lot it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not very familiar with the frameworks you're using, but I’ll take a stab at it:

Your first block of code has the behavior it does because `ToList` takes a snapshot of the current set of rows that match the criteria. When you add a new row, you’re adding an item to that snapshot, but aren’t touching the database from which the other rows were retrieved.

The second block of code has the behavior it does because the context keeps track of a cache of local objects. The first line that calls [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.load.aspx) just brings those items into the cache, but the objects that were previously in the cache are left there as local objects.

From my limited knowledge, this would be the best solution:

1. When the form is first created, create a [`BindingSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx). Set this `BindingSource` as the [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.aspx)’s [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.datasource.aspx). Set the `BindingSource`’s [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource.aspx) to `context.Items.Local.ToBindingList()`. Now the `BindingSource` functions as a proxy to the cached items.
2. When an item is selected, [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.load.aspx) the appropriate entities as you’re doing now, but then also set the [`Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx) of the `BindingSource` appropriately. (The documentation suggests the syntax for `Filter` should be the same as [`DataColumn.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) accepts—it looks SQL-like, so I bet there’s some way to turn a Linq query into an appropriate string.)

The overall effect is that you’ll be using the data from the underlying database. When a category is selected, it will load the appropriate entities. Then it will filter the list of all the entities it has ever known to just those of interest.

Comment: You're right, Is it possible to unload the objects before every selection? I did some reading and disposing is probably the only way to do it, but that doesn't work very well for me.   
I tried your suggestion, unfortunately it's not working for me, perhaps BindingSource Filter isn't the way to do. Thanks

Comment: @Mody: I don't really know what I'm doing, so I've offered a bounty on your question. Hopefully we'll get an answer from someone who knows what they're doing.